# Discord HTTPError [AbortError]: The user aborted a request

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots, cryptocurrency

---

Hello, my bot changes the prices of cryptocurrencies with the name of discord. and it does it randomly between 3, 4, 5 minutes. but I am getting an error like this. I think the bot is blocking the discord when it sends name change requests on too many servers.

If you have a solution/idea, I would be very happy if you could help me.

---

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\crypto-v2\BOTS-1\BTC\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:93
        throw new HTTPError(error.message, error.constructor.name, error.status, request.method, request.path);
              ^

HTTPError [AbortError]: The user aborted a request.
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\crypto-v2\BOTS-1\BTC\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:93:15)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\crypto-v2\BOTS-1\BTC\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async GuildMember.edit (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\crypto-v2\BOTS-1\BTC\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\GuildMember.js:312:5) {
  code: 500,
  method: 'patch',
  path: '/guilds/962762744648585286/members/@me/nick'
}
```

Comment: Your question is very vague, the error doesn't really say much. Edit the question and show your code. Since it's a vendor thrown error, it's most likely implemented wrongly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the bot is blocking the discord when it sends name change requests on too many servers.

Well, discord is blocking your bot from sending these lots of requests by rate limiting you which results in an error. if you would like to just ignore the error and don't change the name just add a .catch(console.log) at the end of whatever function calls that name change.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I'll try and let you know the result.

Comment: The bot does not give an error, but does not change the name :D

Comment: Hi, Yes, You should try avoiding to change the name too often as it's a heavy task that discord rate-limits. You should try as a workaround to update the status message with the name you want (ex. "WATCHING Bitcoin: $66,000"). If you want some code, just say in the comments here & i'll be happy to help.

Comment: yes, i'd like you to help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you contact me on discord? @vutu craftit7#9142

Answer (score 0):

---

I've been testing the bot for 1 day and my bot on 500 servers gives this error, my bot on 50 servers works normally.

my bot works like this;
I am pulling data from a site using the node-fetch module and it replaces the data with the bot name.
If you want to review the bots and really want to help, I can share the source code of my bot. https://discord.com/invite/xePcHcGTk9

---

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).